# Assigning multiple array values to variable

Tags: php, arrays, implode

OK I have this

```
 $eng[] = "All";
 $eng[] = "engine_Sigma";
 $eng[] = "engine_K-Series";
 $eng[] = "engine_Duratec";
 $eng[] = "engine_Suzuki";
 $eng[] = "engine_Vauxhall";
 $eng[] = "engine_Crossflow";

do {
$enginetype = explode(":", $items['engineid']);

foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
    echo "$items[wsiid] - $items[code] - $items[incvat] - $eng[$key] <br>
";
}
} while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq));
```

Now instead of it echoing each instance of the value I want to assign ALL the values that would be displayed within the foreach loop to a single variable $test which I can then echo at a later date

I've been trying for the last hour and am close to punching the keyboard.
Any help would be great. Thanks

** ADDED **

So the database query will return values such as 1:3:6 for row 1 in the table
which will mean that it should echo engine_Sigma engine_Duratec engine_Crossflow

Row 2 in the table has value 2 so will only echo engine_K-Series

Row 3 in the table has value 1:2:5:6 which will echo engine_Sigma engine_K-Series engine_Vauxhall engine_Crossflow
Hope that explains it better
I want the values to be assigned to a variable that I can use later on, not just simply echoing the code within the foreach

I also want it to be like 
     $var = "engine_Sigma engine_K-Series engine_Vauxhall engine_Crossflow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$test="";  //Set variable to null
do {
$enginetype = explode(":", $items['engineid']);

foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
    $test .="$items[wsiid] - $items[code] - $items[incvat] - $eng[$key] <br>
";
}
} while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq)); 

echo $test; //display test
```

Comment: Sort of working, however 
The first row in the table has 1:3:6 as the values & the 2nd row has just 3
so the rows should echo 
engine_Sigma engine_Duratec engine_Crossflow
engine_Duratec

instead its displaying 
engine_Sigma engine_Duratec engine_Crossflow 
engine_Sigma engine_Duratec engine_Crossflow engine_Duratec 
engine_Sigma engine_Duratec engine_Crossflow engine_Duratec engine_Sigma engine_Duratec engine_Crossflow 
plus a lot more a repeated values in the same lines most of the way down the page

Comment: works !
I had the $test =""; in the wrong place !
     $test = "";
     foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
     $test .= "$eng[$key] ";
  
     }
 echo $test.'<br />';

does exactly what i want , thanks everyone else for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a variable outside the scope. Something like the following:

```
$values = [];
do {
    $enginetype = explode(":", $items['engineid']);

    foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
        $values[] = "$items[wsiid] - $items[code] - $items[incvat] - $eng[$key]";
    }
} while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq)); 


// Somewhere later
foreach($values as $value) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```